# Error message during boot

Tags: boot, lvm

What does this error mean ?

```
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: clean
```

It was shown during startup but the system booted fine.

Do I have to do anything?

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not an error. It just means that your filesystem has been marked "clean", meaning no issues.

No issues at all with that message, in fact it's good to see it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but if all is fine I don't understand why the message keeps showing.  Normally there should be no message during the startup at all.  Just want to know, could you pls explain that to me ?

Comment: @SukreeKaeomanee the utility `fsck` will show if the filesystem is clean or not. This is normal, there is probably a way to disable it but I'm not aware of one. You can research that further. Please remember to accept and upvote my answer if it helped you.

Comment: @SukreeKaeomanee If the booting is fine then you should open a new question for the video card problem. It's not exactly like a forum here.